# Were the Israelites affected by the first three plagues in Egypt?

Tags: exodus, moses

In the fourth plague: the "swarms of flies", the Bible says:

> "And in that day I will set apart the land of Goshen, in which My
>   people dwell, that no swarms of flies shall be there, in order that
>   you may know that I am the Lord in the midst of the land." (Ex 8: 22)

So, were the Israelites affected by the first three plagues?

Comment: I don’t think the passage you are using is the best for this question. “Then Pharaoh summoned the wise men and the sorcerers, and they, the magicians of Egypt, also did the same by their secret arts.”
‭‭Exodus‬ ‭7:11‬ ‭“But the magicians of Egypt did the same by their secret arts. So Pharaoh's heart remained hardened, and he would not listen to them, as the Lord had said.”
‭‭Exodus‬ ‭7:22‬ ‭“But the magicians did the same by their secret arts and made frogs come up.”
‭‭Exodus‬ ‭8:7‬ ‭“The magicians tried by their secret arts to produce gnats, but they could not.”
‭‭Exodus‬ ‭8:18‬

Comment: Plus it’s Exodus not Genesis

Answer (score 2):

Exodus 8:22-23 shows that God chose to protect his people from the plague of flies.  This was to make a distinction between His people and the people of Egypt.  God protected his people from the fourth and the fifth plagues.

It also tells us that God's people were in the land of Goshen which was located in the eastern part of the Nile Delta and certainly some distance away from where Pharaoh and his household lived.

The Bible does not say whether His people suffered the consequences of the first, second and third plagues, only that God saw fit to protect His people from that point on.

Answer (score 0):

The third plague afflicted "all of Egypt." (Exo. 8:17) So it would appear that yes, they experienced the first three.

Comment: Welcome to Bible Hermeneutics SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803).

Comment: Hi @Howard, welcome to the site! Could you expand a little on your answer? Do you believe "all Egypt" included the Israelites or might it be just Egyptians?